# Button removed with removeChild() gets re-added in it's over state

Tags: actionscript-3, simplebutton

I have a SimpleButton on the stage, and in the click event for it, I remove it using `removeChild()`. When re-adding the button, it gets re-added in it's "over" state, not the "up" state as expected.

I'm pretty sure it's a bug, so I've filed a JIRA: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-31445, my question is now on how to fix it, if anybody's had a similar experience.

What I've tried:

- using `visible = false` instead works, but I'd prefer to remove it off the stage altogether as the game I'm working on can have a lot of popups/screens.
- Firing the `mouse_out` event manually - doesn't work, and in any case, the `mouse_out` event fires as expected (perhaps before resetting to the up state, it makes a check to see if it's added to the stage, finds out it's not, then quits early)
- Resetting the stage focus - I thought it was a problem with the stage focus, as you were losing focus when the button was hidden, but resetting it didn't fix it.
- I could temporarily swap the over and up state when it's hidden, but that seems like an ugly fix.

Comment: can you post the code? because i tnink it is not a bug, but some logical mistakes inside the code.

Comment: If you follow the link to the jira, there's a zip containing a project and code

Comment: hmm, just took a quick look at it. Seems like a bug to me too. I noticed that I didn't had the bug playing it in my Flash Player or in FireFox. (I only got it in IE and Chrome). Maybe you should just make your own custom button?

Comment: Are you giving the button an instance name? If you are, try not giving it an instance name (just to see if that works). If you need an instance name, modifying `visible` is probably the way to go.

Comment: from documentation about upState: ||| Specifies a display object that is used as the visual object for the button up state — the state that the button is in when the pointer is not positioned over the button. ||| Since the removal of the object is taking place there is no MOUSE_OUT event happening, otherwise when you using visible false, it is happening.

Comment: @rvmook: what version of fp do you have? bug is present in the debug player, chrome (latest fp) and firefox.

@Jackson: instance name doesn't have any effect. I'd go with `visible`, but the game I'm making has a lot of screens, and I'd prefer not to have all that on the display list

@Jevgenij: The mouse_out is firing normally after the click event. If you download the project from the jira, there's trace statements for the different events

Answer (score 1):

I've been Having this problem as well, removing one button and adding another in response to an Mouse up event on a separate sprite.. IE the mouse isn't over either of the buttons at the time, But when the first button (the one with the problem) was previously removed the mouse was indeed over it so it hadn't received a mouseOut event and retained itself in the over state. Using visibility to work round this which is ok for my needs BUT the alternative answer would be to replace with a new instance of the button before adding it to the Display List.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Noisy. There is a mouseOut event being fired on the button however (download the code from the jira and you'll see), which is why I think it's a bug. Replacing it with a new instance isn't a bad idea, but I don't like creating new objects when I don't have to, and it breaks when you're using Flash for your art (i.e., and artist might do a GUI for you. In that case, the button itself it's set to export, just the parent GUI)